# Why does my input element drop a line when i use Float:left

Tags: css

I have used a CSS style sheet for W3 schools which defines columns of 25% and 75%.  I wanted to add two more column types of 10% and 65%

I copied the .col-25 class and renamed it .col-10 and adjusted the width to 10%

When I add this class to an input field the resulting form displays the input on the next line down and 100% wide

Can anyone explain what I have done wrong?

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

input.invalid, textarea.invalid, select.invalid
{
    background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Style inputs, select elements and textareas */
input[type=text], select, textarea{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: vertical;
}

/* Style the label to display next to the inputs */
label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: right;    
}

/* Style the submit button */
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.my-button{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

/* Style the container */
.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Floating column for labels: 25% width */
.col-25 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  text-align: right;
}

/* Floating column for inputs: 75% width */
.col-75 {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

/* Floating column for inputs: 10% width added by Malcolm but will not     display correctly */
.col-10 {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col-10, .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```
<body>
GOODS RECEIPT NOTE  
<div class="container">
  <form name="f1" id = "f1" >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="haulier">Customer : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="customer" name="customer" placeholder="Customer name">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="haulier">Haulier : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="haulier" name="haulier" placeholder="Haulier name">
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="vehicle_registration">Vehicle registration : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="vehicle_registration" name="vehicle_registration" placeholder="Vehicle registration">
      </div>
    </div> 

     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="airwaybill">Airwaybill : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input type="text" id="Pfx" name="awb_pfx" placeholder="Pfx">
      </div>
      <div class="col-25">
        <input type="text" id="airwaybill" name="airwaybill" placeholder="Airwaybill number">
      </div> 
    </div>

     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="shipper">Shipper : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="shipper" name="shipper" placeholder="Shipper name">
      </div>
    </div>


     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="consignee">Consignee : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="consignee" name="consignee" placeholder="Consignee name">
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="destination">Destination : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="destination" name="destination" placeholder="Consignment destination">
      </div>
    </div>    


      <div class="row">       
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="pieces">Pieces : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="pieces" name="pieces" placeholder="Number of pieces">
      </div>
    </div>    




    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="documents">Documents : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <select id="documents" name="documents">
          <option value="">Please select</option>
          <option value="yes">Yes</option>
          <option value="no">No</option>          
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="subject">Comments : </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <textarea id="comments" name="comments" style="height:100px"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">

      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
<input type="button" class="my-button" name="btn_grn" id="btn_grn" value="Create goods receipt note">
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="errors"></div> 

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Print GRN & labels">

</div>


</body>
```

Comment: You should provide both html and css code.

Comment: Thanks,  can I do that after asking a question?  I find the Stackoverflow interface rather confusing.  I had to use the space bar and tap 4 spaces on each line of the css just to get it displayed properly.

Comment: Of course use the edit option. Quick tip about the code block input (the 4 spaces is annoying!): just put \`\`\` then newline <code> then another newline and again \`\`\`. all the text between the two lines with \`\`\` will be code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I see the issue here.  I copied your code to [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/mYLZma) and it looks to be working as expected.  The only change I made was creating/adding a `.col-65` class as you mentioned to the input next to the 10% width one, and everything is responsive and taking up one line.  Is that not the result you're looking for?

Comment: The result I see in Chrome is an input field 100% wide on the line below the label. Is there an option to upload a screen shot?

Comment: In the Codepen as well, or just on your own project? I'm using Chrome and the pen appears like [this](https://imgur.com/a/qY9Rdfp).

Comment: Just my own project. I think I'll drop this style sheet as I just looked at the page on my android tablet (Chrome desktop) and the input fields are all messed up!

Comment: Yeah, if it's different than the pen for you, there's some other CSS somewhere that's affecting it, so take a look with the inspector and see what other rules are there.